# how to show an alert message when on a final page

Tags: javascript, php, html, hyperlink

i have created a dynamic table, that displays a list of records from a recordset  with a previous and a next link using php and adobe dreamweaver.
what i am trying to achieve is to show a message whenever there are no more records to display, and the next link is still clicked,

presently what i have been able to achieve is when ever you navigate to the final record a message is shown, to let you knw you are on the last page of the records using "show region"

```
<?php if ($pageNum_quiz >= $totalPages_quiz) { // Show if last page ?>
            On the last record page
            <?php } // Show if last page ?>
```

so for example on viewing this last record, and the next link is still clicked, i want a message to be shown like "there are no more recordsto be shown".
 how can i implement this.

Comment: no how, do u understand my question

Comment: Perhaps not. Though your actual problem is that there's a next link on your last page. There shouldn't be.

Comment: What happens if someone clicks previous on the first page? Sometimes the best solution is to simply remove the offending buttons all together.

Comment: please dont bother about the previous button, all i need is a solution for the next button

Comment: I would just write code to hide the next link once the last page is reached

Comment: thats not the point, the point is i just want to display a message when on the final record and the next button is clicked, infact it has to be clicked so they know there are no more records

Comment: omg so i cant get an ansa hmmm

Comment: People get annoyed when they click on links just to find out that there's nothing on the next page.  The ideal situation is to not display the "next page" link on the last page of results.

Comment: huh i knw, but still i have a reason for this